# Yii db->beginTranscation in yii

Tags: yii

when using,

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
```

After this code cant update and insert data in Database.

Why?

Comment: You asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447834/how-to-give-db-connection-in-db-begintransaction.
Check answer under it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do a proper commit and for get eventual error 
you should follow the common scenario

```
try
{
   $transaction= Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
   Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql1)->execute();
   Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql2)->execute();
   //.... other SQL executions
   Yii::app()->db->commit();

}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    Yii::app()->db->rollBack();
}
```

In this way you can manage exception and show the eventual reason of yor fails   or  see the result in db after you do the commit.