# How to give db connection in db beginTransaction

Tags: yii

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();



                        try {


                           $transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();

                           $model   = new UserRole();
                           $model->role_name="new";
                           $model->save();

                            $transaction->commit();
                            Yii::log('Done', 'trace', 'stripe');
                       } 
               catch (Exception $e) {
                     $transaction->rollback();
                        }
```

Why data's are insert in db after that begintransaction in yii,What is $connection?i dont exactly what is meaning of $connection.
In My config.php My Db connection like below.

```
'db' => require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.php'),
 $connection = array(
'connectionString' => "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx",
'username' => "root",
'password' => "",
'charset' => 'utf8',
'emulatePrepare' => true,
'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
);
```

My databse connection in another file database.php

I got error like,

```
Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object.
```

Why data's are not insert after that beginTransaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. set correct db connection params in your config file:

```
'db' => array(
    'connectionString' => "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx",
    'username' => "root",
    'password' => "",
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
)
```

or write connection data in database.php and include it in main config:

in **database.php**

```
return array(
    'connectionString' => "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx",
    'username' => "root",
    'password' => "",
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
);
```

in **main.php** (or other config file)

```
'db' => require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.php'),
```

**2**. define `$connection` varaible before using:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;

try {
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

    $model = new UserRole();
    $model->role_name = "new";
    $model->save();

    $transaction->commit();
    Yii::log('Done', 'trace', 'stripe');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if (isset($transaction)) {
        $transaction->rollback();
    }   
    Yii::log('Error', 'trace', 'stripe');
}
```

Comment: $connection = array(
'connectionString' => "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx",
'username' => "root",
'password' => "",
'charset' => 'utf8',
'emulatePrepare' => true,
'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
);
return $connection;in my database.php file i return connection like these.but not insert data.

Comment: Please read full answer (second part too). define $connection varaible before using.

Comment: Yes i changed  $connection = Yii::app()->db;
                            try {               $transaction=$connection->beginTransaction(); but not working still